# Need to combine vector layers, but not with merge (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, merge, vector-layer

I have four overlapping vector layers.  Each is a grid with a single field of interest:  `numpoints`.
I want to create a single output layer that is a single grid, with a field `sumpoints` that is the sum of the `numpoints` field in each of the input grids.

The grids overlap, but not completely.  I want the output vector layer to have a single grid cell if *any* of the input layers have a grid cell at that location.  However, I don't want the output layer to have "stacked" cells, so I don't think merge, with subsequent field math, works.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could run `centroids` on all four layers, then `join attributes by nearest`, then do the field math, then `join attributes by location` to any of the grids.